# Meteor object available in Console, but throws 'cannot read property findOne of undefined

Tags: javascript, meteor, publish-subscribe

I'm new to Meteor and I've been stuck on this problem for hours.

I've created a collection in a file 'sessions.js' at imports/lib/sessions.js

```
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import { Mongo } from 'meteor/mongo';

Sessions = new Mongo.Collection('sessions');
```

I've created a few documents in the database using the browser console. I then want to return one document using the template helper:

```
import { Template } from 'meteor/templating';
import { Sessions } from '../../../../imports/lib/sessions.js';

Template.CarCamping.helpers({
    test: function() {
        return Sessions.findOne({name: 'David'});
    }
});
```

This throws the following error:

```
debug.js:41Exception in template helper: TypeError: Cannot read property 'findOne' of undefined
    at Object.test (http://localhost:3000/app/app.js?hash=e301d24dd47ccd4c73ae01a856896ad67acaaca0:77:32)
    at http://localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?hash=ef41aed769a8945fc99ac4954e8c9ec157a88cea:2994:16
    at http://localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?hash=ef41aed769a8945fc99ac4954e8c9ec157a88cea:1653:16
    at http://localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?hash=ef41aed769a8945fc99ac4954e8c9ec157a88cea:3046:66
    at Function.Template._withTemplateInstanceFunc (http://localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?hash=ef41aed769a8945fc99ac4954e8c9ec157a88cea:3687:12)
    at http://localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?hash=ef41aed769a8945fc99ac4954e8c9ec157a88cea:3045:27
    at Spacebars.call (http://localhost:3000/packages/spacebars.js?hash=65db8b6a8e3fca189b416de702967b1cb83d57d5:172:18)
    at Spacebars.mustacheImpl (http://localhost:3000/packages/spacebars.js?hash=65db8b6a8e3fca189b416de702967b1cb83d57d5:106:25)
    at Object.Spacebars.mustache (http://localhost:3000/packages/spacebars.js?hash=65db8b6a8e3fca189b416de702967b1cb83d57d5:110:39)
    at ._render (http://localhost:3000/app/app.js?hash=e301d24dd47ccd4c73ae01a856896ad67acaaca0:30:22)
```

What I've tried already:

- Made sure autopublish is on, so it's not a problem in subscribing or publishing data.
- Made sure creating collection isn't only done on server. The path 'imports/lib/sessions.js' is accessible for both client and server if I understood correctly.
- The html contains the template tags with template name

The thing is: When i query the db from the console using 'Sessions.findOne({name: 'David'});' it does give me the expected result. But from the code itself it's not working.

Help is much appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You are not exporting `Sessions` from `imports/lib/sessions.js`, so when you go to `import` it, `Sessions` won't be defined. Try this:

```js
import { Mongo } from 'meteor/mongo';

export const Sessions = new Mongo.Collection('sessions');
```

You can see a similar pattern with the `Todos` collection [here](https://github.com/meteor/todos/blob/master/imports/api/todos/todos.js).

Comment: Thanks for this answer. This indeed solved the problem of the data not printing in the templates. But when i add a property to the return statement, like this: 'return Sessions.findOne({name: 'David'}).name' I get an error saying: cannot read property 'name' of undefined. The name does show in the view, but the console doesn't let me access the collection and its objects?

Comment: So it sounds like the original problem is solved. Your follow-up questions are related, but I can't give them thorough treatment in a comment. Here are some quick thoughts: (1) There could be several reasons but it sounds like you need a guard - see [this article](http://dweldon.silvrback.com/guards). (2) The collection was a global in your original code, and is now an exported variable. See [this forum topic](https://forums.meteor.com/t/meteor-1-3-modules-support-is-there-a-way-to-access-ecmascript-exports-in-the-browser-console-meteor-shell/20034/1) for ideas on how to handle this.